# not accessible local host 127.0.0.1 of squid proxy server in ubuntu

Tags: proxy, squid

I have configure squid proxy server on ubuntu 11.10. it's working fine but when i accessed local host 127.0.0.1 in firefox browser it shows an error unable to connect & Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1. Please can you tell me where should be change in the squid.conf file for accessing the local host.

Answer (score 1):

If my memory isn't failing, browsers have an exception by defalut and don't use proxy for connections to localhost. Try to remove that in the browser configuration.

And then, check squid.conf if you have a line like "http_access deny to_localhost".